# Regular expression match any string within a quote or null

Tags: regex

For example I have a file with multiple lines, some of the lines have a string `"SocialInsuranceNumber": "123456789",` while some may have `SocialInsuranceNumber": null,`. I need to find all such lines by using regular expression. And eventually replace the value after `:`.

Any suggestion how to write a regex in this case?

Comment: Try `"SocialInsuranceNumber"\s*:\s*(?:"\d+"|null),`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
"SocialInsuranceNumber"\s*:\s*(?:"\d+"|null),
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3456Dv/1).

The pattern matches:

- `"SocialInsuranceNumber"` - a literal char sequence
- `\s*:\s*`  - a hyphen enclosed with 0+ whitespaces (`\s*`)
- `(?:"\d+"|null)` - a non-capturing with two alternatives:

  - `"\d+"` - `"`, 1+ digits, `"`
  - `|` - or
  - `null` - a   sequence of literal chars
- `,` - a literal comma